# What is the equivalent of Alter ignore table in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a join table, created for habtm relationship. Earlier I had created an index for that table, but then i wanted to add the unique true attribute to the index, i wrote a new migration for that, which should remove the old index and create the new one. But the problem is my database already contains some duplicate values, in mysql we have the way to use 
alter ignore table. As:

`ALTER IGNORE TABLE pst_nw ADD UNIQUE INDEX (add1, add2, add3, add4);`

What is its equivalent in rails. How can we specify the ignore flag through migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct one-line equivalent to `ALTER IGNORE TABLE` functionality in rails.

Might be a good idea to split the functionality into two:

1. Remove duplicate data
2. Add unique index

The first task can be accomplished by running the `ALTER IGNORE TABLE .. ADD UNIQUE INDEX..` step followed by a `DROP INDEX` step as part of a script (rake task / separate script / running the queries directly in mysql, etc.) which will need to be run only one time.

The second would then be a simple `add_index` migration.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I also had done, used the Alter ignore table.. add unique index.. from the database, and used the ruby code in migrations to achieve the task, but this is not the correct way, I think, since what I think is all the work related to db should be done through our ruby code only. This way actually feels to me separates the integration of the ruby code with the db.

Comment: You can still run the `Alter ignore table.. add unique index.. drop index` step as part of a ruby script/rake task as I mentioned above. However, it should not be part of a migration since this is not something that should be reversible. i.e. you don't want to get back to a state of having duplicate rows by rolling back a migration.

Comment: okay, I got your point. are you talking about running raw sql query by the rake task, if otherwise, can you help me with the syntax?

Comment: Right, I meant running the raw sql query within the rake task. There is no equivalent in rails for the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

My approach was to run a raw `ALTER IGNORE` SQL query with `execute`, then drop that index and re-add it the "Rails way" for consistency in my schema:

```
class AddUniqueIndexesToPstNw < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute "ALTER IGNORE TABLE `pst_nw` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `drop_me` (add1, add2, add3, add4)"
    remove_index :pst_nw, :drop_me
    add_index :pst_nw, [:add1, :add2, :add3, :add4], unique: true
  end

  def down
    remove_index :pst_nw, [:add1, :add2, :add3, :add4]
  end
end
```

Comment: `alter ignore` was removed from mysql 5.7